# How can I complete my solution in function problem?

Tags: functions

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ with $f(x)f(y) - f(xy) = x + y$ for every $x,y \in R$.
>
> Prove that:
>
> a)$f(0) = 1$
>
> b)$f(x) = x + 1$

My solution:

a) $f(x)f(y) - f(xy) = x + y$

$f(0)f(0) - f(0\cdot0) = 0 + 0$

$f(0)^2 - f(0) = 0$

$f(0)[f(0) - 1] = 0$

Therefore $f(0) = 0$ or $f(0) = 1$

Since I must prove that $f(0) = 1$, I should reject the first solution. I can't figure out how though...

b) $f(x)f(y) - f(xy) = x + y$

By replacing $y$ with $0$

$f(x)f(0) - f(0\cdot0) = x + 0$

$f(x)\cdot1 - 1 = x$

$f(x) = x + 1$

Comment: Look what happens in your calculations in bart b) if you assume $f(0)=0$. Can you derive a contradiction?

Comment: I thought about that, $x = 0$ comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take f(0) to be 0, replacing **x** by **0** and **y** by **1** we get:

**f(1)·f(0) - f(0·1) = 0 + 1**

**f(1)·0 - 0 = 1**

**0 = 1**

Which is a contradiction. Therefore, f(0) must be 1.

Comment: 5 seconds faster :(

Comment: I'm really sorry :O

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks fine. For the rest of (a), take $x=0$ and $y=1$. Then $f(0)f(1)-f(0)=1$, which does not work for $f(0)=0$.